# How to get a value of hidden field in webload radview javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to webload (radview) and trying to retrieve value of hidden filed.

Below is the html

```
<input type="hidden" name="hidCurrentPanel" value="tabFindCase">    
<input type="hidden" name="hidFilterDate" value="">
<input type="hidden" name ="hidemployeeid" value ="1116"
```

I tried something like this

```
var getEmployeeID = GetElementValueByName("hidemployeeid");
InfoMessage("Employee id is " + getEmployeeID );    
wlHttp.FormData["hidemployeeid"] = wlHttp.GetCurrentValue("hidemployeeid",getEmployeeID )
```

but getEmployeeID is returning blank

Comment: try `document.getElementsByName`

Comment: getEmployeeID is being returned as `null` or an empty string ? From blank, I assume it's an empty string

Comment: document.getElementsByName is not supported in webload javascript. getEmployeeID is returning empty string.